# How to remove 0 before 10 in owl carousal?

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I have created an Owl carousel with fraction pagination count "01 / 010". I just need to remove the number 0 before 10 when the total slide number is greater than 9, otherwise, it will remain the same as it.

```
$(function(){
$('.ivySlide').owlCarousel({
  smartSpeed: 500,
  items: 1,
  margin:0,
  nav:true,
  dots:false,
  onInitialized:counter,
  onTranslated:counter
});
function counter(event) {
  var element = event.target;
  var items = event.item.count;
  var item = event.item.index + 1;
  var sldtxt = $('.active .ivySlideTxt').html();
  var sldWidth = 100;
  var sldPercent = sldWidth * item / items;
  $('#counter').html("0"+item+" / 0"+items);
  $('.slTxt').html(sldtxt);
  $('.slideState span').css("width", sldPercent + "%");
  $('.slideState span').html(sldPercent + "%")
}
});
```

Please check the link here - https://codepen.io/tsarkar/pen/NmpGmV

Comment: If you have created this, then I would think you should know your own code and can see you can just remove the second `0` from `$('#counter').html("0"+item+" / 0"+items);` So it looks like `$('#counter').html("0"+item+" / "+items);`

Comment: Agreed, except I would advise to remove every `0` from the expression.

Comment: Seems you have only added 0 as prefix. Please remove and run :)

Comment: $('#counter').html("0"+item+" / "+items); this is not a solutions, please check the answer below what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `item` and `items` are less than 10 or not and prefix `0` accordinlgy

```
$(function(){
$('.ivySlide').owlCarousel({
  smartSpeed: 500,
  items: 1,
  margin:0,
  nav:true,
  dots:false,
  onInitialized:counter,
  onTranslated:counter
});
function counter(event) {
  var element = event.target;
  var items = event.item.count;
  var item = event.item.index + 1;
  var sldtxt = $('.active .ivySlideTxt').html();
  var sldWidth = 100;
  var sldPercent = sldWidth * item / items;
  if(item<10) {
    item = "0"+item;
  }
  if(items<10) {
     items = "0"+items;
  }
  $('#counter').html(item+" / "+items);
  $('.slTxt').html(sldtxt);
  $('.slideState span').css("width", sldPercent + "%");
  $('.slideState span').html(sldPercent + "%")
}
});
```

Comment: happy to help you :)